# Customize Django Form

Tags: django, django-forms

Have a basic question about how to show to  tags in one  within Django framework.
I would like my HTML table looks like:

#### HTML Table Object:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell1</td>
    <td>Cell2</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

#### Current Django code

```
from django import forms

class PFAMInp(forms.Form):
    Cell1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea (attrs={'cols': 20, 'rows': 2}))
    Cell2 = forms.FloatField(required=True)
```

Later I am using Python to convert this Django form into HTML on GAE.

#### Python code to generate html

```
class PFAMInputPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        html = html + str(PFAMdb.PFAMInp())
        self.response.out.write(html)
app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', PFAMInputPage)], debug=True)
def main():
    run_wsgi_app(app)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My question is:
Is there a way to customize this django template to make it show two  in one row, rather than showing two  tags? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option of calling the form using `Form.as_p()` or `Form.as_ul()` which will print the form as a series of `<p>` tags or `<li>`tags, respectively.

[The full API specification is here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/)

Here's an example of how this might work:

```
from django import forms

    class PFAMInp(forms.Form):
        Cell1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea (attrs={'cols': 20, 'rows': 2}))
        Cell2 = forms.FloatField(required=True)

    pfami_form = PFAMInp().as_p()
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried Cell2.as_ul(), but failed. Would you minding giving me a little more directions?

Comment: Sure. You've created two fields there but you need to instantiate and then operate on an instance of PFAMINP. So you've created your form class, but from there you need to create an instance of that class like `myform=PFAMInp` and then to display using `<p>` tags, call `myform.as_ul()`.

Comment: I think I understand your approach. I use python to print this class into HTML table 'html = html + str(PFAMdb.PFAMInp())'. If I want to have <td> tags, I should create a separate class, and run 'html = html + str(PFAMdb.PFAMInp)sub().as_ul())' right?

Comment: I just edited my example above to illustrate one approach. Take a look and see if that makes sense.

Comment: It did not work in my setting... But I got your idea. Thanks for your help!